# Is there any way I can create group and invite users using REST API?

Tags: api, rest, yammer

Is there any way I can create group and invite users using REST API? 
I have tried this one
**Request** 
POST https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json
{
"name": "test name",
"private": false,
"description": "A test group" 
}

**Response**
Client error response [url] https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json [status code] 404 [reason phrase] Not Found

**Update**
Group Creation API is working. Now need to know how I will invite user on that group.

Comment: Okay, the Group creation API is working though it is not documented on their API Documentation. The **token** was missing.

Comment: Now I need to know How to invite user into new group using API

Answer (score 0):

try to send the parameters in the URL,
POST
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?name=test_name&private=false

Comment: No need to send it using query params. It is working using POST params. Now I need to know how I will invite user.

Comment: NO, it will invite user to your account. But I want to invite user to a particular group.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this is to impersonate each user and add to group. - http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2015/07/31/yammer-restful-api-how-to-bulk-add-members-to-a-group.aspx

Comment: yes, I saw that. Actually I have checked all the available link in the net. And I don't think it is the way to invite a user to a Group. Anyway thanks, I am contacting with their support. Lets see what they say about it.

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to that endpoint : https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/group_memberships.json?group_id=[:group_id]&user_id=[:user_id]&approve=1 
Use an access token from a verified admin, it will invite the user and validate his invitation in the same time.